# MS Learn Python - code not running in Visual Studio (newbie)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, input, command-line

I am new to programming and have started the Microsoft first steps with Python course. I have navigated the installation of Python (3.9), Visual Studio Code, the Python extension for Visual Studio and have started into some of the practice exercises.

I have tried to run some of the practice programs but am not having much success. To try and identify the source of the problem, I have copied the provided Microsoft code from one of the examples. The issues appear to be as far as I can tell from my extremely limited understanding:

1. The program is not running/partially running; and
2. The program is returning the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

My assumption is that this might have something to do with Visual Studio set up as the output from the Microsoft example code does not match the provided output.

The source code is

```
print("Today's date?")
date = input()
print("Breakfast calories?")
breakfast = int(input())
print("Lunch calories?")
lunch = int(input())
print("Dinner calories?")
dinner = int(input())
print("Snack calories?")
snack = int(input())
total = breakfast + lunch + dinner + snack
print("Calorie content for " + date + ": " + str(total))
```

The terminal output I am getting after running the program three times is:

```
PS C:\Users\domch\OneDrive\5_CPD\Python learn\Hello> & C:/Users/domch/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/domch/OneDrive/5_CPD/Python learn/Calorie counter/calories.py"
Today's date?
& C:/Users/domch/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/domch/OneDrive/5_CPD/Python learn/Calorie counter/calories.py"
Breakfast calories?
& C:/Users/domch/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/domch/OneDrive/5_CPD/Python learn/Calorie counter/calories.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\domch\OneDrive\5_CPD\Python learn\Calorie counter\calories.py", line 4, in <module>
    breakfast = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '& C:/Users/domch/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/domch/OneDrive/5_CPD/Python learn/Calorie counter/calories.py"'
PS C:\Users\domch\OneDrive\5_CPD\Python learn\Hello>
```

I understand the 'solution' to this example code is supposed to look like this in the terminal:

```
Today's date?
December 7th, 2020
Breakfast calories?
250
Lunch calories?
300
Dinner calories?
500
Snack calories?
150
Calorie content for December 7th, 2020: 1200
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the program 3 times but actually attempting to run it when the previous run is still expecting your input (look at what the version read as input (it is in the error message from `ValueError` exception:

> '& C:/Users/domch/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
> "c:/Users/domch/OneDrive/5_CPD/Python learn/Calorie
> counter/calories.py"'

. Look for a terminal tab within VS Code and enter the input there on the first run.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.

If I understand correctly, what is missing from the code is the input for the variables i.e. date, calories etc?

Comment: No, rather, instead of inputting a value your script asks for, you are attempt to run it again.